# Can I draw two things in a popup form, an image and text?

Tags: c#, gridview

In C#, I have a form (using winforms) that has a Gridview with data in it.  When I hover over a cell in the GridView, I use the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events to popup a second form which has an image in it.  I'm using DrawImage to place this with the following code:

```
    private void frm_MouseOverPicture_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Point MyPoint = new Point(250, 10);
        Point MySecondPoint = new Point(10,10);

        Font myFont = sender as Font;
        Brush myBrush = sender as Brush;
        Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle(250, 10, 500, 500);

        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Graphics g2 = e.Graphics;
        Bitmap MyBitmap = new Bitmap(@"C:\Javie\IMAP0001.jpeg");


        //g.DrawImage(MyBitmap, MyPoint.X, MyPoint.Y);
        g.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(MyBitmap, myRect);
        //g.DrawString("Hi", myFont, myBrush, MySecondPoint);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("hi", myFont, myBrush, mySecondPoint);          

    }
```

My question is that when I try and then add the string by using a separate DrawString method, the popup form gets a big Red X in it as If I can't draw two things in the same form (which is just a control,  right?).

Comment: This won't solve your main problem, but if you don't dispose of the bitmap, you will end up with a memory leak. Either wrap it in a `using` statement, or (much better), load the bitmap into a local field on load, then you won't have to load it from file every time the form is painted.

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView`!! This is wrong and confusing and and bound to get wrong answers wasting everybody's time.. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type, but when asking for help here is __not__ the time to be so lazy..! -

Answer (score 2):

The myFont and myBrush objects do not look correct. Try:

```
        Font myFont = (sender as Form).Font;
        Brush myBrush = new SolidBrush((sender as Form).ForeColor);
        ...
        e.Graphics.DrawString("hi", myFont, myBrush, MySecondPoint);
```

assuming sender is a Form, or create them directly:

```
        using (Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 16))
        {
            using (Brush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue))
            {
                using ( Bitmap MyBitmap = new Bitmap(@"C:\Javie\IMAP0001.jpeg")) 
                {
                    ...
                    g.DrawString("hi", myFont, myBrush, MySecondPoint);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you do go with the second option, be sure to dispose of the `Font` and `Brush` when you're finished with them, ideally through a `using` statement. If you don't do this, you will experience memory leaks.